# Knockout: copy values from one model instance into another model instance

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have two Knockout Model instances (ModelInstance1 and ModelInstance2). For both instances all bindings are already applied and page is loaded with two different forms.

One form is visible for user and allows user to do inline editing. FOr this form I use ModelInstance1.

Another form is modal form that appears on Edit button click. This form uses ModelInstance2. If user clicks Cancel, then no values are saved to database and modal form is closed.

Now I need on my custom event (imagine as it would be button click) to copy all values from one instance to another.

Of course, I can do like this manually:

```
 ModelInstance2.FirstName(ModelInstance2.FirstName());
 ModelInstance2.LastName(ModelInstance2.LastName());
 etc.
```

but is there any other way to do this?

Take into account that my Model contains observables, observable arrays, computed and subscriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the constructor function for your model so that it can take a plain object as an initializer. Then you can clone a model by doing

```
var modelInstance2=new Model(ko.utils.parseJSON(ko.toJSON(modelInstance1)));
```

You need to serialize to JSON and then parse the result to get a deep copy (properties that are reference types like objects and arrays are actual copies and not references to the original). If you did

```
var modelInstance2=new Model(ko.toJS(modelInstance1));
```

then you'd get a shallow copy and changing any reference-type property in `modelInstance2` would also change it in `modelInstance1`.

Comment: still this doens't allow repply binding, right? It seems that it doens't work when modelInstance2 was already binded.

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
var Model = function (firstName, lastName) {
    var self = this;
     self.FirstName = ko.observable(firstName);
     self.LastName = ko.observable(lastName);
     self.clone = function () {
         return new Model(this.FirstName(), this.LastName());
     };
}

var instance1 = new Model('Jon', 'Smith');
var instance2 = instance1.clone();
```

If you had the knockout mapping extension available you could always do this....

```
var temp = ko.toJS(instance1);
var instance2 = ko.mapping.fromJS(temp);
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

If you dont want to maintain a method that clones the object then mapping is a good option, I can think of no other way to handle it. These seem to be your options.

Comment: I hav emore then 20 properties, including arrays, computed values  etc. Also I have different subscribtions for instance1 and instance2, your approach will loose them. I need to copy values and not init new model.

Comment: @renathy I don't understand.. this simply shows you a way of encapsulating that logic as opposed to having to duplicate it time and time again. There was no way of knowing exactly what kinds of properties etc would need to be copied from your example... this would work with observable arrays... computed values simply would not need to be copied at all.

Comment: it doens't work, it doesn't update values. I guess it would work on page load, but not after binding, am I wrong? Instance2 already was created before.

Comment: Well that is because you have applied bindings against an instance... you would need to reapply bindings.

Comment: How to reapply bindings?